# How to connect remote debug to a bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I tried to remote debug my minecraft server plguin, I followed this guide: https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-remote-debugging-with-bukkit.92081/, but it isn't working, always throws error:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

I'm not making stiupid mistake like typing wrong port or somethink or debuging without server started, and really haven't got idea why it's can't connect.
My server arguments: `java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8243,suspend=n -jar "Craftbukkit 1.12.2-R0.1.jar"
pause`
What is weird it's seams like eclipse actually connects to the server but it's refuse it, because if i change suspend argument to y, and press debug button in eclipse server starup is processing. Weirdest think is always when I close eclipse if I pressed debug button at last once, server gives output: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8243` Pls help me with this. What I'm doing bad?
P.S. When I create simple java program export it, and then try to remote debug every think works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using eclipse or NetBeans or Intellij?

But for all basicly:

1. Go into **Run/Debug Configuration**
2. Add a **Remote** Connection
3. **Host: localhost** // **Port: 8243** // leave rest as is
4. `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8243`

So maybe your problem was that you didn't adapt your **IDE** Settings to your port?